# TestRestTemplate can't reach /v3/api-docs endpoint during test

Tags: springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have springboot 3 application with springdoc.
I making a junit test which try to validate the swagger schema using a TestRestTemplate.
I am making this request:

```
@Autowired protected TestRestTemplate webClient;

@Test
public void test() throws IOException {
    String content = this.webClient.getForObject("/v3/api-docs", String.class);
```

I get a exception as response:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.putAll(java.util.Map)" because the return value of "io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Components.getSchemas()" is null
at com.mycompany.config.SwaggerConfig$ActuatorCustomizer.customise(SwaggerConfig.java:198) ~[renault-spring-boot-starter-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
at org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.lambda$getOpenApi$6(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:364) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
at org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource$$Lambda$1122/0x000000004147bd48.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
at org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.lambda$getOpenApi$7(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:364) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
at org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource$$Lambda$1121/0x000000004147bb20.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178) ~[na:na]
at org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource.getOpenApi(AbstractOpenApiResource.java:364) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-common-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
at org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiResource.openapiJson(OpenApiResource.java:124) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
at org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiWebMvcResource.openapiJson(OpenApiWebMvcResource.java:111) ~[springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:6.0]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.10.jar:6.0.10]
at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:6.0]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.10.jar:10.1.10]
```

it fails because in my config I have a OpenApiCustomizer to add an operation on a ping (which a redirect of health actuator)

```
@Component
public static class ActuatorCustomizer implements OpenApiCustomizer {
  @Autowired private PingParameters pingParameters;

  public void customise(OpenAPI openApi) {
     openApi.getComponents().getSchemas().putAll(ModelConverters.getInstance().read(pingParameters.getResponseClass()));
                Schema<Object> healthSchema = new Schema<>();
                healthSchema.setName("Health");
                healthSchema.set$ref("#/components/schemas/Health");
                Operation operation =
                        new Operation().description(pingParameters.getNotes())
                                .tags(Collections.singletonList("Ping"))
                                .parameters((List<Parameter>)
     pingParameters.getExtraParameters());
                operation.setResponses(new ApiResponses().addApiResponse("200",
     createApiResponse("ping", healthSchema)));
                PathItem pathItem = new
     PathItem().description(pingParameters.getSummary()).get(operation);
                openApi.getPaths().addPathItem(pingParameters.getPath(), pathItem);

 }
```

When I do   openApi.getComponents().getSchemas() there is no components existing and it fails.
But when I run application it's working
I try to fix using

```
 openApi.schema(resolvedSchema.schema.getName(),resolvedSchema.schema);
```

to avoid to make a getComponent but the point is, at the end, I only get Ping operation in my schema

Comment: Ok, I found the issue, it's because in my test class I used another @ContextConfiguration than my Application class :)